# rust/mdBook: 404 page displays without CSS if the address is a subfolder

Tags: http-status-code-404, documentation-generation

Using mdBook for a documentation website, I have a displaying error when the 404 page is in a subfolder.

Example:
https://docs.luos.io/wrong-subfolder/wrong-page.html -> 404 page without CSS (subfolder in address)
https://docs.luos.io/wrong-page.html -> 404 page with CSS (no subfolder in address)

It's as if the `{{ path_to_root }}` variable wasn't taken into account in index.hbs when displaying a 404 page, but only when the address has one or several subfolders in it. Any idea on how to resolve this?

I realized also that `{{ path_to_root }}` variable was not processed in .md files, only in index.hbs.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Here is a partial answer:

index.hbs must have the `base_url` set in order to default the 404 page at `\` (making it works even if the wrong address is in a subfolder).

This must be included in index.hbs:

```
{{/if}}
{{#if base_url}}
<base href="{{ base_url }}">
{{/if}}
```

This resolves the 404 displaying problem.

--

However, this doesn't answer the question about `{{ path_to_root }}` not being rendered in .md files.

Don't hesitate to add details if needed.

Answer (score 1):

As stated [here](https://rust-lang.github.io/mdBook/format/configuration/renderers.html).

Put in your `book.toml`:

```
[output.html]
site-url = "/YOUR-SUBDIRECTORY-HERE/"
```

(slash before and after subdirectory)

if your book is at:

http://youruser.github.io/YOUR-SUBDIRECTORY-HERE/index.html